# pdf downloaded from Website is corrupted + Empty doc when opened

Tags: pdf, download, asp-classic

our Classic ASP website hosted on IIS 7 on windows 2008 32 bit server.

Website allows used to download pdf files from it.

When I try to download and open the pdf file i see the message "There was an error opening this document. This file is damaged and could not be repaired."

If I copy the pdf manually from the website folder to my local machine I am able to open the pdf. But when I download the same pdf from website, i am not able to open. The pdf file size and number of pages are correct. But When I open the pdf it is empty.

I am not sure what is causing this issue, Kindly check how to trouble shoot the pdf download and the error while opening it.

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: In most of the case it's an error in the ASP code (e.g. wrong Content-Length or ASP content included with binary PDF data). You can browse HTTP headers or body in browsers dev tools. If you can, add your code to the question.

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF file or a link that can be used to download it. We can't troubleshoot what's wrong with a PDF file if we don't have a PDF file to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. We worked with network team and resolved the  issue. Recent changes to the Network settings was affecting the file download. Now settings are changed (for Non Compliant HTTP) to allow the download from this website. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should verify if you are actually using the same viewer software to preview PDF. When you open PDF in browsers they may use different actual apps/engines to display PDF:

- Google Chrome uses [its own built-in PDF viewer](https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/Db-PRsynPM4);
- Internet Explorer may use [Adobe Reader app as plugin](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Acrobat-plugins-Internet-Explorer-10-q82531.aspx) or [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) as plugin;
- Firefox uses [PDF.js to display PDF](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) since version 19;

Standalone viewers may include [Adobe Reader](https://www.adobe.com/) (version 10 and 11 have different handling malformed pdf files), [Foxit Reader](http://foxitsoftware.com/) or less known specific viewers like [ByteScout PDF Multitool](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html).

If your PDF file is having minor internal issues with incorrect data or corrupted objects then it may cause error messages with some readers but others may automatically walkaround this issue. For example, Adobe Reader 10 (including IE plugin version) may throw the error if at least single font description object contains incorrectly formatted font description  while version 11 or later handles such files without issues. In other words even different versions of the same pdf reader application may behave differently in some cases.

*Disclosure: I'm connected with [ByteScout](https://bytescout.com/), the maker of PDF Multitool free viewer.*

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Your response is very helpful. Issue was with network settings and download works fine after changing the network settings..

Comment: @user3219354 thank you for the update! oh, the matching of the file size was the first thing to check actually that I forgot - great that you found and fixed the issue!